# What is causing this box?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a strange box appearing around a form:

[image]

Here is the HTML:

```
<div class="container">
      <h4>Please login</h4>

  <form action="/client_scripts/login.php" class="form-horizontal" method="post" role="form">
    <fieldset>
      <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-xs-4">
          <input class="form-control" placeholder="Username" name="username" type="text">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-xs-4">
          <input class="form-control" placeholder="Password" name="password" type="password">
        </div>
      </div>
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Login</button>
    </fieldset>
  </form>

  <hr />
  <div class="footer">
    <p>Powered by <a href="#">SOMETHING</a></p>
  </div>

</div> <!-- /container -->
```

I see nothing in the HTML to cause it?

Comment: have a look at the css for styling questions, not at the html

Comment: There must be some custom css you applied somewhere. I copied your code to test it and there is no border: http://www.bootply.com/VOPiaqCcx1

Comment: Inspect the element in google chrome..to know what is causing it..

Answer (score 3):

the strange box according to you is `<fieldset>`. and because of it's default property it's showing some border and  it's property.

Try this to neutralize the default property of fieldset and you would get rid of it or you can style as according to your need.

```
fieldset{border:none;padding:0;margin:0;}
```

Comment: you can always check by inspecting element, check on other pages if the `fieldset ` is taking css property from other places.

Comment: The page with the border has glyphicons CSS loaded (fieldset{border:1px solid #c0c0c0;margin:0 2px;padding:0.35em 0.625em 0.75em;}
) why does Glyphicons play with forms???

Comment: then that must be from the default css by bootstrap. You can overwrite that if you don't want this default properties by embeding your css custom css file below bootstrap css.

Comment: it only happens when I have the glyphicons CSS loaded... why would glyphicons alter form appearance?

Comment: as you have already said above your glyphicons CSS contains style `fieldset{border:1px solid #c0c0c0;margin:0 2px;padding:0.35em 0.625em 0.75em;}` so it's obviously taking this part css property and applying to your fieldset